# How to escape apostrophe in a db2 sql query, running within a shell script?

Tags: sql, shell, db2

I'm trying run a query that will include static columns in its output. The select statement works when I run it via the CLP, but not when I execute it within a shell script:

```
su - myid -c 'db2 connect to mydb;db2 -x -v "select COL1,'','',COL2,'','',COL3L from MYTABLE fetch first 10 rows only"; db2 connect reset;'
```

When I run this, the output error I get is:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "," was found following "select COL1,".
Expected tokens may include:  "<select_sublist>".  SQLSTATE=42601

SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003
```

I've even tried putting the select statement in a variable and inserting that within the statement, but still the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. -Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape the single quotes as with a backlash as in :

```
su - myid -c 'db2 connect to mydb;db2 -x -v "select COL1,\'\',\'\',COL2,\'\',\'\',COL3L from MYTABLE fetch first 10 rows only"; db2 connect reset;'
```

Beware, I didn't test it... no shell at hand just now.

**UPDATE:**

Finally I got my hands on a DB2 instance.. after a little testing i got it working.
It turns out that the previous syntax was faulty. The proper way of quoting the single quote is (in this case) '\'' as in:

```
su - myid -c 'db2 connect to mydb;db2 -x -v "select COL1,'\'','\'',COL2,'\'','\'',COL3L  from MYTABLE fetch first 10 rows only"; db2 connect reset;'
```

That's because the single quote around the whole command must be closed (') in order to supply the escape for the single quote in the db2 query (\') and then reopened to resume the command quoting ('). Weird as it looks, it works....

This is the command I used to test it:

```
bash -c 'db2 connect to mydb;db2 -x -v "select 1,'\'','\'',2,'\'','\'',3  from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 fetch first 10 rows only"; db2 connect reset;'
```

Comment: Thanks your your reply @carlo-pellegrini
Tried that and got the following **0403-057 Syntax error at line 6 : `"' is not matched.**

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I would never have found this on my own. Again, I really appreciate your help on this!